Finding the closest permutations to two permutations
I'm working on a genetic algorithm that would solve a Substitution Cipher, so it's solving for a specific permutation of the alphabet. I'm trying to breed two members of the population. Let's say their genomes are A and B, unique permutations of the alphabet. How could I generate a new permutation C that is a reasonable "average" or "midpoint" between the two permutations A and B?
One method I thought of was assigning an index to each letter in both A and B, and constructing a permutation C by taking the averages of the indices of the letters in A and B and placing the letters in C according to those indices (after solving for conflicts). Is this a valid approach?
Since I would like some variation in my breeding so that it wouldn't be completely deterministic (as to create a more diverse population), is there another method that would allow for such flexibility? I suppose I can introduce some of that variation by settling the conflicts mentioned above randomly.

It sounds like if $A$ goes to $E$ in one permutation you assign index $5$ and if $A$ goes to $Q$ you assign index $17$ so the average would b $11$ and $A$ would go to $K$.  Is that what you mean?  It doesn't sound like a meaningful average to me.

Another option is to get the lexicographic index of permutations A and B, take the mean, and then generate permutation C from that.

One idea is to construct a directed graph with edges $i\to\pi_A(i)$ and $i\to\pi_B(i)$ and then take a random walk to generate the child.  Explicitly, for each $i$ let $\pi_C(i)$ be either $\pi_A(i)$ or $\pi_B(i)$, each with probability $1/2$.

Upvote. This feels much more like what genetic breeding does in the real world than any "find a midpoint" implementation that the OP requested.

This sounds great! I'll have to go figure out exactly how to do that, but it really does sound like what I'm looking for.
Out of curiosity, is the fact that it's possible for the permutation to consist of multiple cycles a problem for using a directed graph?

No, it doesn't matter.  For each node, just take one of the (up to two) outgoing neighbors as its successor in the new permutation.

So you're saying if from every last step, I randomly choose which next place to go to from either parent, I'll eventually wind up where I started having visited all options? Again, if it's multicyclic, I assume I have to detect cycles and then choose a random member outside all the established cycles to continue the algorithm. But that works? That's just mind blowing haha.

Sorry if my use of the term random walk caused confusion.  You don't even need a graph.  Just select, for every node in any order, one successor node from among the (up to two) candidates.  You could even do this simultaneously if you want because the choices are independent.
